# How to configure Hylafax to send faxes to folders?

Tags: freepbx, fax, elastix

At my current job, we have an established phone/fax system that uses Elastix on top of FreePBX and Hylafax. The guy who set it up did so by himself (a former employee we still have on contract as needed), and many attempts to request information on how he set it up, usually result in him insisting he fix our issues himself (all the while not really sharing any information about the system). We're trying to make it where faxes (we have different lines for specific departments) get sent electronically to a storage location on our network. Any ideas on how to accomplish this? I know I'm not providing much information about the actual situation, but I will be happy to provide any information I can.

Thanks in advance for any help and advice!